# nodejs elementtree npm etree.write() pretty printing

Tags: node.js, parsing, elementtree, pretty-print

I have ran into a problem while using the etree npm for nodejs. I am extensively using the elementtree npm in my application so I cannot afford to change the npm. I am writing the XML using the below code.

```
var et = require('elementtree');
tailorData = fs.readFileSync(XML_FILE).toString();
etree = et.parse(tailorData);
// Do some changes in xml
var resultXml = etree.write(); // DOES NOT DO PRETTY PRINTING
fs.writeFileSync(tailoredXML, resultXml);
```

etree.write() messed up the whole XML and my later processing is halted. It does not put endline after the tags. This is how the XML looks like now.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Tailoring id="1234"><status>incomplete</status><Profile id="CIS_LEVEL_1"><title>CIS_LEVEL_1 Security Profile</title><select idref="file_group_owner_grub2_cfg" selected="true" /><select idref="file_user_owner_grub2_cfg" selected="true" /><select idref="file_permissions_grub2_cfg" selected="true" /></Profile></Tailoring>
```

Below is my expectation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Tailoring id="1234">
<status>incomplete</status>
<Profile id="CIS_LEVEL_1">
<title>CIS_LEVEL_1 Security Profile</title>
<select idref="file_group_owner_grub2_cfg" selected="true" />
<select idref="file_user_owner_grub2_cfg" selected="true" />
<select idref="file_permissions_grub2_cfg" selected="true" />
</Profile>
</Tailoring>
```

Is their any way I can acheive the above result in nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the way to do it. Using the very light weight npm "pretty-data" for achieving this.

```
var pd = require('pretty-data').pd;

var et = require('elementtree');
tailorData = fs.readFileSync(XML_FILE).toString();
etree = et.parse(tailorData);
// Do some changes in xml
var resultXml = etree.write();
resultXml = pd.xml(resultXml); // THIS WILL DO THE PRETTY PRINTING.
fs.writeFileSync(tailoredXML, resultXml);
```